# How to continue a while loop in bash if certain message printed by program?

Tags: bash, while-loop, break, continue, bcftools

I'm running a bash script using some software which follows the basic pattern below.

```
while read sample; do
    software ${sample} > output.txt
done <samples.txt
```

For certain samples this message is printed: "The site Pf3D7_02_v3:274217 overlaps with another variant, skipping..."

This message does not stop the software running but makes the results false. Therefore if the message is given I'd like to stop the software and continue the while loop moving onto the next sample. There are lots of samples in samples.txt which is why I can't do this manually. A way of denoting which sample the message is for would also help. As it is I just get many lines of that message with out knowing which loop the message was given for.

Is it possible to help with this?

Fyi the program I'm using is called bcftools consensus. Do let me know if I need to give more information.

Edit: added "> output.txt" - realised I'd stripped it down too much

Edit 2: Here is the full piece of script using a suggestion by chepner below. Sorry it's a bit arduous:

```
mkfifo p
while IFS= read -r sample; do
    bcftools consensus --fasta-ref $HOME/Pf/MSP2_3D7_I_region_ref_noprimer.fasta --sample ${sample} --missing N $EPHEMERAL/bam/Pf_eph/MSP2_I_PfC_Final/Pf_60_public_Pf3D7_02_v3.final.normalised_bcf.vcf.gz --output ${sample}_MSP2_I_consensus_seq.fasta | tee p &
    grep -q -m 1 "The site Pf3D7_02_v3" p && kill $!
done <$HOME/Pf/Pf_git/BF_Mali_samples.txt
rm p
```

Comment: Capture the output of the software in a variable, and depending on the output, stop the process software, and continue while loop. What do you mean by "makes the result false"? The command `software` returns false?

Comment: @stephanmg No sorry I see that's quite unclear - I just mean they results I get are wrong, not that they're false in a boolean sort of way.

Comment: Okay, I know can envision a solution. Note my previous one was incorrect, thanks to @chepner.

Answer (score 3):

I would use a named pipe to grep the output as it is produced.

```
mkfifo p
while IFS= read -r sample; do
    software "$sample" > p &
    tee < p output.txt | grep -q -m 1 "The site Pf3D7_02_v3:274217" p && kill $!
done < samples.txt
rm p
```

`software` will write its output to the named pipe in the background, but block until `tee` starts reading. `tee` will read from the pipe and write that data both to your output file and to `grep`. If `grep` finds a match, it will exit and cause `kill` to terminate `software` (if it has not already terminated).

If your version of `grep` doesn't support the `-m` option (it's common, but non-standard), you can use `awk` instead.

```
awk '/The site Pf3D7_02:v3:274217/ { exit 1; }' p && kill $!
```

Comment: Today I rediscovered named pipes. Thanks for the great example @chepner.

Comment: Shouldn't it likely be `>> output.txt`?

Comment: Possibly, though the OP is using `>`. I got the impression that any previous output from a single run of `software` was effectively invalidated in the event the special message is encountered, so I actually imagine something like `if grep -qm1 "..." p; then kill $!; else : do something with good output.txt; fi`.

Comment: @chepner thanks for the suggestion but it hasn't worked, the software was not stopped for any samples where the message is printed and it all ran as before. Just incase I have not given enough information I've put the whole command lines with your suggestion (used for the particular software) in my post.

Comment: Is it possible that `software` is simply finishing before `grep` has a chance to see and react to the message?

Comment: Can you try the updated answer? I'm not sure if putting the pipeline in the background interfered with the value of `$!`; this might work better, and if not, there's still the possibility of buffering between `tee` and `grep` that could cause an issue.

Answer (score 1):

```
while read -u3 sample; do
    software ${sample} | 
    tee output.txt |
    { grep -q -m 1 "The site Pf3D7_02_v3:274217" && cat <&3 }
done 3< samples.txt
```

The input file is redirected on file descriptor 3. The idea is to eat everything from the 3rd file descriptor if the specified text is detected. Because we redirect output to a file, it's easy to `tee output.txt` and then check grep for the string. If `grep` is successful, then we `cat <&3` eat everything from the input, so the next `read -u3` will fail.

Or:

```
while read sample; do
    if 
        software ${sample} | 
        tee output.txt |
        grep -q -m 1 "The site Pf3D7_02_v3:274217"
    then
        break;
    fi
done < samples.txt
```

Because the exit status of the pipeline is the command last executed, we can just check if `grep` returns with success and then break the loop.